# empty local report in sql server 2008 on windows 7

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have sql server 2008 on windows 7. am trying to design a very simple local report to display just about 10 records in a database table in a report-viewer control on a windows forms application startup form. when i run the application the report shows up, i can see the report header text but it does not show any rows(and there are rows in the table). even when i preview the report DataTable, the rows are there. When i try the same on on windows XP and SQL 2008, the rows appear. any know what i could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

you must refresh your report after databinding. write this line at the end of your code:

```
ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

maybe your datasource name be wrong. your datasource name must like this:

**DataSetName_DataTableName**

Comment: I did this and my report is still empty.  I can see the tablix and it's headers but there is no data displayed.  I know the dataset returns data because I can see the expected row count of 5 when I inspect the ReportDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I followed the guide on msdn but there seems to be steps missing.  Here are 2 examples of what I did.

With BindingSource and TableAdapter:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = _path;
reportsBindingSource.DataSource = reportsTableAdapter.GetData();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("test", reportsBindingSource);            
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

With datatable

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = _rptPath;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(TOR2012()); 
//TOR2012 returns a ReportDataSource built from a data table
reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```